# Allow Python modules to write to disk on AWS Lambda

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, google-search

I am using the Python module googlesearch on AWS Lambda but it is throwing an error - I suspect because it wants to write a cookie to disk according to a folder structure that isnt there on AWS Lambda.

Also, AWS Lambda only allows writing to /tmp/

What to do? The only thing I can think of is to download the module code from github and integrate into my Python script - dont really want to go down that road...

Thanks for any advice...

Here is the AWS Lambda error report:

```
Errno 30] Read-only file system: './.google-cookie': OSError
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/var/task/scriverto.py", line 176, in lambda_handler
url_list = generate_URL_list(query,n) #call URL generator routine in gsearch
File "/var/task/scriverto.py", line 58, in generate_URL_list
for url in search(query, tld = "co.uk", lang='en', pause = 2, stop=n): 
#can also add tld to limit to country e.g. tld='uk
File "/var/task/googlesearch/__init__.py", line 330, in search
get_page(url_home % vars())
File "/var/task/googlesearch/__init__.py", line 151, in get_page
cookie_jar.save()
File "/var/lang/lib/python3.6/http/cookiejar.py", line 1875, in save
with open(filename, "w") as f:
OSError: [Errno 30] Read-only file system: './.google-cookie'
```

Answer (score 2):

Reading the [source code](https://github.com/MarioVilas/googlesearch/blob/master/googlesearch/__init__.py#L88) for the `googlesearch` module:

```
# Cookie jar. Stored at the user's home folder.
home_folder = os.getenv('HOME')
if not home_folder:
    home_folder = os.getenv('USERHOME')
    if not home_folder:
        home_folder = '.'   # Use the current folder on error.
cookie_jar = LWPCookieJar(os.path.join(home_folder, '.google-cookie'))
try:
    cookie_jar.load()
except Exception:
    pass
```

It seems you can set the environment variable `HOME` or `USERHOME` to `/tmp` which will cause `googlesearch` to use those locations for writing the cookiejar to disk.

Comment: Fabulous. Thanks Matt.

Comment: How can I set the environment variable? I tried including home = '/tmp' alongside other arguments such as the query, language, TLD etc. when calling the module from the main script but it throws an error. I cant find a list of optional arguments anywhere on the github page.

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/env_variables.html has instructions for setting environment variables in AWS Lambda

Comment: Great - thanks Matt. I set HOME to /tmp as one of the environment variables on the function page and it looks like it worked.